# Formmail.com with conditions on checkboxes

Tags: html, forms, formmail

Using this service (http://www.formmail.com) on a form and Ive run into a bit of a problem that after extensive google searching has not given me an answer. I want to add who gets an email if a check box has been checked. Ive tried a few JS and PHP solutions and nothing seems to work. The main problem seems to be how the service does the email proccessing by needing `<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="X">` in the form to determine who to email.

Including the checkbox code although its nothing special

```
<form method="POST" action="http://fp1.formmail.com/cgi-bin/fm192"> 
<input name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" value="Yes"/> 
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit"/>
<input type="hidden" name="_pid" value="XXXX">
<input type="hidden" name="_fid" value="XXXX">
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="1">
</form>
```

edit

It send to email 1 now. I want it to also send to email 2 if the checkbox is checked.

Answer.
Found out the answer. Stupid thing wont let me self answer however.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

function oncheckboxclick() {
    var c = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
    var d = document.getElementById("email");
    if (c.checked) {
        c.checked == true;
        d.setAttribute("value", "2");
    }
}

</script>

<input name="Box 1" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="Yes" onclick="oncheckboxclick();"/>

<input type="hidden" name="recipient" id="email">
```

Thanks to whoever put up an answer than retracted it. Gave me enough breadcrumbs to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what they're doing on their end to process the forms, I'd suggest doing this in PHP or some other programming language.  PHP:Mailer is really well documented and adding something like

if ($checkbox == 'YES")
{ add new recipient here}

else
{ proceed as normal}